# What is the Windows equivalent of the command "nc [server_name] [port]"?

Tags: internet-connection, netcat

On linux, one can connect to a server by typing 
`nc pwnable.kr 9000`
on a terminal.

On windows, this does not work in Powershell nor cmd, and also Putty when using Telnet looks at first like it connected, and then whenever I enter something it exits, which is not the behaviour on Linux. So what is the correct way to access this server on Windows and send commands to it?

Comment: [ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/) is available for Windows. Download and install that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. (I just thought that would be something Putty is capable doing)

Comment: I installed it, what should I do now? the commands still do not work. The new application "Nmap - Zenmap GUI" with the above command just shows me that the server is running and the port 9000 is open, but I can't see how to send inputs to the program that the server is running.

Comment: Nmap is something different (it's a port scanner). To use ncat is virtually no different than using nc in Linux. From command prompt type out `ncat pwnable.kr 9000`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may download a portable version of ncat from this site: https://nmap.org/ncat/
It's a beta version (http://nmap.org/dist/ncat-portable-5.59BETA1.zip). If you prefer, you may also use the nmap command for windows provided on this site too.

Answer (score 9):

The Windows equivalent is [Test-NetConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection) - it will test if the connection to the destination works and show certain debug output.

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName superuser.com -Port 443

ComputerName     : superuser.com
RemoteAddress    : 151.101.193.69
RemotePort       : 443
InterfaceAlias   : LAN-Connection* 12
SourceAddress    : 10.254.93.150
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

Comment: No. `Test-NetConnection` will attempt to open a socket and report whether that succeeded. `nc` or `netcat` will give the user an open connection to that socket, so they can enter data that will be sent to the server.

Comment: Generally you're right @CodeCaster. But a lot of admins use nc to check if a connection / port is reachable or open via nc -vz <ipaddr> <port>. This behavior can be replicated on a windows client via the command described above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "tnc" as shortening of Test-NetConnection in Windows Powershell. Legacy Windows command shell doesn't have any equivalent of nc (except third parties).

For example:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> tnc haruncetin.com.tr -p 80

ComputerName     : haruncetin.com.tr
RemoteAddress    : 172.67.208.143
RemotePort       : 80
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 1
SourceAddress    : 192.168.215.119
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was already posted in a comment, and seemingly does not give the required functionality?...